# Python: Replace a character in string

Tags: python

How can I adjust the following function so that if the variable assigned to st1 does not appear at all in string (1 does not appear in string, and the string is `*********)`, the function just returns the string back `(*********)` but if the string does contain 1, it replaces every 1 with 2 as done below. Thank you for your help.

```
def replacest1(string,st1,st2):
for i in string:
    if i == st1:
        N_W = string.replace(st1 , st2)
        return N_W
        print(replacest1("***1***1***","1","2"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need a function.  Given three strings, `foo`, `tok`, and `rep`, simply using `foo.replace(tok, rep)` will return `foo` with all instances of `tok` replaced with `rep`.  If `foo` contains *no* instances of `tok`, it will simply return the original string `foo`.  Additionally, I think the for loop is unnecessary (and probably causing you the most trouble).

Comment: for an assignment, required to replace every instance of st1 with s2. If the string does not contain st1, we just return string.

Comment: BTW, `string` is not a good choice for a variable name: it's the name of a standard module.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Yes, I was just about saying that. It's quite important to NOT choose identifiers like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def replacest1(string, st1, st2):
    return string.replace(st1, st2)
```

Test:

```
replacest1("abcdefdcba", "c", "x")
```

results in:

```
"abxdefdxba"
```

Test:

```
replacest1("yyyyzzzz", "c", "x")
```

results in:

```
"yyyyzzzz"
```

---

Or much much much much better:

```
"abcdefdcba".replace("c", "x")
```

Please note that the function defined above is a 1:1 correspondence to the function demanded by the question. It is **not** a good practice to use `string` as an identifier. I'd strongly recommend **not** to use such kind of identifier.

---

*A note: As the definition of such a function can be eliminated altogether as `string.replace()` still exists while it is deprecated the solution above will still contain the identifier `string` as used in the question. If the function couldn't be eliminated I'd use a different identifier here but as defining an own function isn't necessary at all anyway I let this identifier be as it is for now.*

---

Here is a variant of how to implement that without the usage of `string.replace()`:

```
def replaceCharacters(inputString, findChar, replaceChar):
    assert isinstance(inputString, str)
    assert isinstance(findChar, str)
    assert len(findChar) == 1
    assert isinstance(replaceChar, str)
    assert len(replaceChar) == 1

    buffer = ""
    for c in inputString:
        buffer += replaceChar if c == findChar else c
    return buffer
```

A note: I prefer to use asserts in order to detect programming errors. If performance is not a big issue in your use case these asserts don't cause any trouble but prevent accidentally misusing a function like this: If you accidentally pass wrong parameters the asserts will fail and give you feedback immediately.

Comment: Could you perhaps rename the `string` parameter (perhaps to `source_string`)? I honestly thought you were calling the deprecated [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) function at first.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I am using the deprecated string replace. It still exist though it seems to be no longer documented. I'll update the answer again.

Comment: That should be even better now.